# WinRT XAML UI stalls even though using background thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winrt-xaml

I have an app where activities that aren't likely to finish quickly are run on a background thread. For example, I have some items to display where I show a generic icon to begin with while the background code tries to see if there is an associated image that should be displayed instead.

When XAML tries to fetch the image, if I don't have it already, I add the query to a queue for later processing and temporarily return null. The queue handling basically does this:

- Get a mutex (so that I can manipulate single items safely)
- If the item isn't already in the queue, add it
- If the queue isn't already running, start it
- Release the mutex

The queue is run with this:

```
objectFileQueueRunning = true;
cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
Task.Run(() => ProcessObjectFileQueue(cts.Token));
```

The queue code basically keeps on taking the top item off the list and processes it until we run out of items or the cancellation token gets set. The same mutex is used within the queue code but only when removing the top item off the list and when resetting objectFileQueueRunning to false.

My problem is that the UI thread is basically unresponsive until the queue code finishes running ... even though it is running on a background thread.

I've run performance analysis on the executing app but cannot spot anything that would seem to give me any hints as to what to look at.

Do I need to put a pause into the background thread to give the UI thread a chance to interact with the user? Is it the case that I'm running the background thread so tightly that the UI thread isn't getting a look-in?

Comment: It is hard to understand your problem given the description, but since you mention images I can say that Image controls can stall UI thread. We had a case with about 50-70 Image controls displayed at the same time and on slower computers it would lock UI for several seconds until all images are loaded.

Comment: Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) there is not enough context to know what the answer to the problem might be. Suffice to say, if the UI is unresponsive, _some_ part of your code is blocking it.

Comment: Thanks, @Denis, for your feedback. Did you come up with a good solution?

Comment: @PeterDuniho, I appreciate that I haven't provided a lot of context. Unfortunately, it is not trivial to try and extract a minimal complete code example, which is why I was trying to focus on options like slowing down the background thread in some way.

Comment: "it is not trivial to try and extract a minimal complete code example" -- as far as I know, no one here has promised that you can have your question answered with only trivial effort. Yes, creating a suitable code example requires work on your part. For better or worse, that's part of the cost to you for having other people help you fix your code. You owe it to those volunteering to help you, _and to yourself_, to provide those people with the best information possible. Even if it is non-trivial to do so.

Comment: Well, we did come up with a solution. Basically we switched to virtualized collection to cut down on the amount of image controls created at once and made images smaller. You could still see some stalling on Surface RT, but it was a lot less noticeable. Now, I can't say for sure if that has anything to do with your issue or not.

Answer (score 1):

The solution, in my case anyway, turned out to be the use of StackPanel as the ItemsPanelTemplate coupled with the background thread doing a lot of work.

The problem with using StackPanel is that it causes virtualisation to be disabled, which means that all of the elements get created in one go.

Switching to ItemsWrapGrid allows GridView to use virtualisation and therefore only create elements that are either visible or about to become visible. This, in turn, causes the background workload to be reduced.

The reason I was using StackPanel dates back to when my app was first written for Windows 8.0. Using the default settings caused problems when the user scrolled horizontally because the scroll bar size would vary. This seems to have been fixed in Windows 8.1 but I hadn't thought to revisit the XAML as I updated the app.

Shared in case anyone else hits similar issues.